# can't access own directory in docker created by ADD/chown/chmod in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I try to add ssh private key into docker building from Dockerfile, it looks wired that I can't access it even it looks like I have full permission

```
Docker Version: 1.0.0
Docker host: ubuntu 14.04
```

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV HOME /home/larry

RUN useradd larry && echo 'larry:docker' | chpasswd
RUN echo "larry ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# arrange ssh key
ADD larry.id_rsa $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN \
    chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh &&\
    chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa 

RUN chown -R larry:larry $HOME
```

After I build the image and run into container and su to user `larry`, I got

```
$ id
uid=1000(larry) gid=1000(larry) groups=1000(larry)
$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 5 larry larry 4096 Jun 21 01:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  4096 Jun 21 01:29 ..
drwx------ 2 larry larry 4096 Jun 21 01:29 .ssh
$ cd .ssh
-su: cd: .ssh: Permission denied
```

Maybe I missed some basic concept in docker ? Just wired from normal unix user point of view.

I put this in github as well https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1295#issuecomment-46700769

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just met bug [#6047](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/6047) which basically says they are issues with `chown` when run after `chmod`.

The following Dockerfile will work:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV HOME /home/larry

RUN useradd larry && echo 'larry:docker' | chpasswd
RUN echo "larry ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# arrange ssh key
ADD larry.id_rsa $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN chown -R larry:larry $HOME
RUN \
    chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh &&\
    chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: thank very much for the link to the bug, I noticed the workaround as well, just want to know more about what this happens and why it looks correct inside container, is it problem in aufs ? I had other similar permission problem, better to know detail. Can you provide more technical information ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know any detail about the cause of this issue

Comment: fine, good enough, wait for a while to see whether others can comment more

Comment: Can be a AUFS bug. Thank you. I was wondering I didn't know Linux enough after 15 years experience. Thank you.