# Not able to access folders copied with Docker COPY

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am copying some folders to image during Docker build. Its a simple list of steps :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY . /deploy
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash myuser
RUN chown -R myuser:myser /deploy
```

Now,if i launch this container and switch to **myuser**, i am not able to access any folder inside **deploy** folder but i can access them as **root** user. I have verified permissions on this folder and didn't found any issue there.

Docker Version : 17.12.0-ce

Host : Ubuntu 14.01

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357242/cant-access-own-directory-in-docker-created-by-add-chown-chmod-in-dockerfile

Comment: Interesting part is, i can edit and save any file inside deploy folder but when do ls <folder name> then i get 
ls: cannot open directory /deploy/controllers: Permission denied

Comment: @Henry I am not using chmod anywhere in my case.

Comment: It seems that there are a few bugs with aufs and chmod/chown commands, sometimes with surprising workarounds. Just do a little search to get some ideas to try.

Comment: `deploy` directory gets an ownership of `myuser` . Can you share permissions of  `/deploy/controllers` after running the container?

Comment: -rw-rw----  1 myuser myuser  216 Jan  5 11:26 README.md 

-rw-rw----  1 myuser myuser 2214 Jan 16 09:50 messages.js

drwxrwx---  2 myuser myuser 4096 Jan 16 09:50 constants

drwxrwx---  2 myuser myuser 4096 Jan 16 09:50 controllers


Not able to add new line :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to launch your container with

```
docker run --user=myuser -ti image_name
```

EDIT : 
After reading ([the documentation](http://[https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy])) you have the following syntax :

```
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
```

Therefore your Dockerfile should be more like :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash myuser
COPY --chown=myuser:myusergroup . /deploy
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't worked out. Have updated my question a bit. Actually i can access deploy folder but not sub folders inside that.